# Simple Click on button is not working (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

index.html

```
type <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>`your text`
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="twitter.jpg" id="tv">
    <button id="btn" >OK</button>
    
</body>
</html>here
```

main.js
`$("#btn").on("click",function (){ $('#tv').hide(); })`
When I click on button nothing happens

when I write a special function in main.js and call it from index.html, it works

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to be ready before adding the event listener? The `#btn` element probably doesn't exist yet when `$("#btn")` is run.

Comment: Try writing the $("#btn") code after the body tag is closed

Comment: Where and how add document ready?

Comment: II load the script main.js after the body tag and everything works. Thank you very much!